# Wordpress - How to add new components in the template panel of the document sidebar?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

Is there a way to add a TextControl component or any other element inside the template panel?
[image]

The [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/slotfills/plugin-post-status-info/) shows how to insert items in the Status & Visibility panel, but I couldn't find how to do it for the other panels.

Answer (score 0):

The section for "Template" has moved to **Summary** since this question was posted. The Documentation for extending [PluginPostStatusInfo](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/slotfills/plugin-post-status-info/) shows the old UI at the time of writing. The UI in WordPress 6.1.1 appears as:
[image: Page Summary]

The `PluginPostStatusInfo` slot is still used to append content to the *Post/Page > Summary* section.

Eg. Adding a text control:

```js
import { registerPlugin } from '@wordpress/plugins';
import { PluginPostStatusInfo } from '@wordpress/edit-post';
import { TextControl } from '@wordpress/components';

const AddMyTextControl = () => (
    <PluginPostStatusInfo>
        <TextControl
            label="My Text"
            ...
        />
    </PluginPostStatusInfo>
);

registerPlugin('add-my-text-control', { render: AddMyTextControl });
```